# Entity Framework Guid Id and foreign key record not inserted

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, guid

```
public partial class Authors
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }        
    protected ICollection<Books> Books { get; set; }
}
```

`Authors` table has a `Guid` primary key and I signed it attribute to generate database.

```
public class Books
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ISBNNumber { get; set; }
    public Guid AuthorId { get; set; }

    public virtual Authors Author { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BookStoreEntities1 context = new BookStoreEntities1();

        Authors author = new Authors();
        author.Name = "Sample Author Name";

        Books authorBook1 = new Books();
        authorBook1.ISBNNumber = "11145-8854-9987";
        authorBook1.Name = "Book 1";

        Books authorBook2 = new Books();
        authorBook2.ISBNNumber = "4145-8854-2987";
        authorBook2.Name = "Book 2";

        author.AddBook(authorBook1);
        author.AddBook(authorBook2);

        context.Authors.Add(author);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

And I created client code to insert a new record into the database. This client code is inserting author to `Authors` table, but not inserting `Books`.

If I change `Author Id` as `int` (not `Guid`), in this case `Author` and `Books` are inserted in database.

What do you think about this?

Comment: Why have you protected the member  `protected ICollection<Books> Books { get; set; }`

Comment: When you say changing Author Id to int are you referring to Author.Id or Books.AuthorId?

Comment: @BhushanFirake: That's the answer :)

Comment: @Slauma i know..i thought OP will figure it out due to my cment

Comment: @BhushanFirake: I meant, it's not too bad to write it as answer, that's what the answer section is for :) BTW: It also doesn't work with an `int` key if the collection is `protected`. I bet the OP changed the collection accidentally to `public` at the same time.

Comment: Hmm, EF can deal with `private/protected` properties. It depends on what `author.AddBook` does. @bayramucuncu could you show the internals of that method?

Comment: Author class is partial and the other part is including AddBook() method. I protected to isolate ICollection<Book> from user code.